# ASP Bizarre Session COM+ Object Lost!

Tags: session, iis, asp-classic, com+

I'm needing a lot of help from yours.

I have an application in ASP, not ASP.NET ... Which uses several COM+ components developed for me.

Below is an example of using one of the components.

```
Dim componentXPTO
Dim xpto

componentXPTO = Server.CreateObject("NAMESPACE.XPTO")

Set xpto = componentXPTO.myFunction(variables)

Set Session("XPTO") = xpto

Set componentXPTO = Nothing

Set xpto = Nothing

---------------------------------

Session("XPTO").name
```

The problem I'm experiencing is something intermittent. I access several times the variable XPTO in the session without any problems. Thus this code is running. What happens is that sometimes when I access the same variable XPTO in the same user session bellow error occurs:

```
| 27 | 800a01ce | The_remote_server_machine_does_not_exist_or_is_unavailable: _'Session (...). name '
```

My suspicion is that as the XPTO object was returning from a COM+ function is keeping dllhost reference to the process and the moment that the recycling mechanism(Lifetime 10 minuts) terminating the process a reference to this object is lost and for this I am getting this error in my application ...

It has some logic that I'm talking about? Return of functions with references and keeping at the time of the recycling process loss this reference?

I've tried every way to debug and the only question that remains is exactly this ..

Please someone help me!

Answer (score 0):

More information about this problem.

On my investigation, my component function return a xpto and xpto is a VB Class contains other functions and some properties.

If my application invoke the asp session to gave a xpto class(from com+) and the dllhost of the component function moments was recycled the com+ stub have a null reference correct?
And this message was appers

```
| 27 | 800a01ce | The_remote_server_machine_does_not_exist_or_is_unavailable: _'Session (...). name '
```

This is the problem, i have a class from com+ reference in my session and my component service uses a recyclind and pooling strategy?